# Algorithm for identifying a geodetic graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms

A graph $G$ is **geodetic** if there exists a unique shortest path between any pair of vertices in the graph.

According to Wikipedia, any graph can be recognized as geodetic in polynomial time, but there is no reference for this fact. I'm not familiar with algorithms, so I was hoping someone could provide a reference.

This is for a little side project, for context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea, using the fact that matrix multiplication can be done in polytime:

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of your graph $G$, and let $n$ be the number of vertices in $G$. Label the vertices $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$.

The entry $(i,j)^{th}$ entry in the matrix $A^k$, which I will refer to as $(A^k)_{i,j}$, counts the number of walks of length $k$ from vertex $v_i$ to vertex $v_j$. So the distance between $v_i$ and $v_j$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that $(A^k)_{i,j} \neq 0$. Further, there is a unique geodesic from $v_i$ and $v_j$ if and only if $(A^k)_{i,j} = 1$ (for this same number $k$).

---

So an outline of an algorithm that shouldn't be too slow is as follows:

**(1)** Get the adjacency matrix $A^1$ of the graph, and make a list $L$ of all the pairs such that $(A^1)_{i,j} = 0$.

**(2)** multiply $A$ by itself to get $A^2$. For each entry in $L$, we do the following:

**If** the entry $(A^2)_{i,j} = 0$, then leave the pair $(i,j)$ in $L$.

**If** $(A^1)_{i,j} = 1$, then remove the pair $(i,j)$ from $L$ (we know there is a unique geodesic, so this pair of vertices is fine).

**If** $(A^1)_{i,j} \geq 2$, then terminate the algorithm and return that the graph is NOT GEODETIC.

**(3)** Check if $L$ is empty. If $L$ is empty, terminate the algorithm and return that the graph IS GEODETIC.

Repeat this process (all 3 steps) for all $k \leq n$. So calculate $A^3$, check each pair in $L$ and update $L$. Do the same for $A^4$, $A^5$ and so on. At some point, either $L$ is empty or you get the failure condition in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

You are not entirely correct, i.e., the Wikipedia entry on [geodetic graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_graph#Computational_complexity) does explain how polynomial-time recognition can be obtained.

Indeed, one way to do this is to first solve the subproblem of counting all shortest paths between two vertices. This is easy to do with a BFS with many solutions online, see e.g., [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/graph-number-of-shortest-paths). Once you have that subroutine, you can run it on each non-adjacent pair of vertices.